# To have an action is equivalent to have a group homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $X$ a set. It's written in my course that

> Having an $G\times X\longrightarrow X$ is equivalent that to have a group homomorphism $$(G,\cdot )\longrightarrow (\text{Bij}(X,X),\circ)$$
>   where $\text{Bij}(X,X)=\{f:X\longrightarrow X\mid f\text{ is bijective}\}.$

For the implication, I defined the action $$*:G\times X\longrightarrow X$$ defined by $$(g,x)\longmapsto g*x$$
and the application $$\tau: (G,\cdot )\longrightarrow (\text{Bij}(X,X),\circ)$$
defined by $$\tau(g)(x)=g*x$$
for all $x\in X$. I had no problem to show that $\tau$ is an homomorphism. But for the converse, I don't know how to do. Given $\tau$, do I simply define $g*x=\tau(g)(x)$ ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it